# Can I have different default phone numbers for different actions?

Tags: contacts

Take a contact which has several phone numbers... say `Home`, `Mobile` and `Work`. When I click the QuickContact action to text them, it asks me which number... so I select `Mobile`. Now, I'd like to set this as default... because I always text them on their mobile. Problem is, when I do this, it ALSO sets it as the default phone for `ACTION==CALL`, which I do NOT want, as I regularly call them on all three numbers.

Is there any way to set a default number for texting while NOT having a default for calling, so that it will still prompt me to pick a number when I click QuickContact.Call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set separate default numbers.  However what you could do is set a shortcut to message that contact and leave the default number empty so it can prompt you when you call.  To set a message shortcut: long press on the Home-screen, select "Shortcut", then select "Direct Message".  This will launch your default messaging app to send a message to that contact to whichever number you set when you create the shortcut.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess this could be a workaround; though hardly ideal. Ideally it would be a method that would carry through to all instances where the QuickContact badges and placards are used.

Comment: @eidylon True, but I don't think you can accomplish that.